# Proving continuity of $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} \quad x\in\;]1,\infty[$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} \quad x\in\;]1,\infty[$$

How to show that $f(x)$ is continuous ?
I think I should use that $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}f_n(x) = \lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^n} = 0 $$
then use uniform convergence of $f(x)$, but I don't see how to prove this uniform convergence

Comment: You mean $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+x^k}$, right?

Comment: No, $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$, maybe my notation is not really clear

Comment: The terms of a series going to zero as $n$ goes to infinity is the minimum you need. It will not guarantee continuity, and doesn't even guarantee convergence.

Comment: Ok, but if I use that $f_n(x)$ is continuous $\forall x \gt 1$, and then I use uniform convergence, does it imply $f(x)$ continuity ?

Comment: Take a look at the hints given here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} \underbrace{<}_{x>1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^n}=\frac{x}{x-1},$$ where in the equality we have got the sum of a geometric series.

Thus, for $m>n$ it is

$$|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|=\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^k} \underbrace{<}_{x>1} \sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{1}{x^k}=\frac{1}{x^{m-1}(x-1)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any $\epsilon > 0$, the series converges uniformly on $[1+\epsilon, \infty)$.

Comment: I have a lot of troubles with uniform convergence. On $[1+\epsilon,\infty)$, we have $\sup f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+(1+\epsilon)^n}\simeq \frac{1}{2+n\epsilon}$. And we have $f_n(x) \lt \frac{1}{2+n\epsilon}$. Is it enough to show uniform convergence ?

Comment: As $\sum \frac{1}{2+n\epsilon}$ converges to 0